# How to annotate an image overlay using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, annotations

I want to annotate an image using overlay by drag and drop(any images). Is there any way I can achieve it through Jquery and ajax. I have found some tutorial [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/12/annotation-overlay-effect/).

But I couldnt find anything on adding it dynamically. Any help appreciated. Thanks.